# go net/http package speed is different between OSX and Linux

Tags: linux, macos

Found that the response time using net/http package is different between OSX and Linux. Basically OSX is slower than Linux. Especially the result is remarkable when I call an internal domain access. More than 10 times OSX is slower... It might come from the go compile, but not sure. Anyone know why such a difference is happen?

- OSX: 10.11
- Linux: centos-7.0-64, it runs on VM of mac

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    url := "http://yahoo.co.jp"

    start := time.Now()
    resp, _ := http.Get(url)
    log.Println(time.Since(start))
    defer resp.Body.Close()

}
```

Result(avarage)
- OSX:   233.662409ms
- Linux: 147.108599ms

Comment: Where are you seeing 10x slower? There's a difference of 58%, which could be due to local network conditions (is one on WiFi?), network configuration and DNS lookup times.

Comment: What are the outputs of `go version` and `time go run main.go` on each system? Go compiler performance can change dramatically from version to version. (i.e. go 1.5 has ~2x slower compiles than go 1.4; see https://golang.org/doc/go1.5#performance)

Answer (score 0):

10x slower is from internal VIP access, so I don't put it. I tried to do with other client as curl and ruby and found that OSX's time_namelookup was significantly slow. So, it's not language, but the DNS cache like function issue on mac. I will look for the detail. Thanks for the information!

go version: 1.5.1 darwin/amd64